# Custom adaptor onClick isn't registering click

Tags: java, android, onclick

I've got the following code which when I click each row, it's not registering the onclick event and the log isn't being displayed.

I'm probably doing something stupid so any help really will be appreciated.

```
public void loadTable(){
     File dbfile = new File(Global.currentDBfull); 
     SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);

     mItemName.clear();
     mItemID.clear();
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

     String SQLStatement = "select * from assets where areaobjectid = '" + StationObjectID + "' and CriticalAsset = 'Y'";
     Log.e("SQLSTATEMENT", SQLStatement);

     String intCount = "0";

     Cursor c = db.rawQuery(SQLStatement, null);  
     if(c.getCount() != 0) {

     c.moveToFirst();
     while(!c.isAfterLast()) {

         mItemName.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Description")));
         mArrayClick.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("StationObjectID")));
         mItemStatus.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ConditionID")));
         Log.e("MITEMSTATUS",c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ConditionID")));


        c.moveToNext();

     }

     rowCount = mItemName.size();

     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvAssets);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   
     int[] colors = {0, 0xFFFF0000, 0}; 
     listView.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
     listView.setDividerHeight(1);

     listView.setAdapter(adapter);


     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

             Log.e("TOMTEST", "Clicked");   

           }
       });


     } else {

        Log.e("Assessment", "No Results");  


     }

     db.close();
}

class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return mItemName.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ImageButton btnAction;

        LayoutInflater inf=getLayoutInflater();
        View v=inf.inflate(R.layout.iconrow, arg2,false);
        ImageView ivStatus=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        btnAction = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.btnAction);

        final String itemID =  "Item ID";
        final String itemText =  "Item Text";
        final String itemStage = "Item Strage";

        tv.setText(mItemName.get(arg0).toString()); 

        String currentStatus = mItemStatus.get(arg0).toString();
        if(Functions.isNullOrEmpty(mItemStatus.get(arg0).toString())){
             ivStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.ico_not_verified); 
        } else if(mItemStatus.get(arg0).toString() == "99") {
            ivStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.ico_not_found); 
        } else {
            ivStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.ico_found); 
        }


        return v;
    }


}
```

Comment: Is your `loadTable()` function called multiple times?

Comment: Yeah it is actually, on the onresume and oncreate

Comment: Try to put some `Toast message` instead of `Log.e("TOMTEST", "Clicked");` in `listView.setOnItemClickListener`.

Comment: I have tested with this and found it is not printing log but able to show toast message on item row click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works well for me.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

                 Log.v("TOMTEST", "Clicked");   
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked : "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }
           });
```

It will show Toast with correct position also.

Somehow it is not able to print message in log.

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: It works well for me. I have created sample demo for that and it works like a charm.

Comment: May I know how your `ListView` is declared in yout layout file?

Comment: @Pratik Sharma It doesn't look like you'll ever receive the xml listing, but can you tell me what you would be looking out for?

Answer (score 0):

if you are `extends`ing `ListActivity` you should `override` the `OnListItemClick` method. It is what you need.  Also, if I can give you a suggestion, the pattern in your `getView` should look like:

```
 if(arg1==null){
   LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
   arg1=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
 }
```

in order to avoid waste of memory, since the `ListView` as your way to recycle the `View` in order to get the memory usage lower

Comment: If i do that, it says you need to implement missing items, and adds the onitemclick back

Comment: you should ovveride it at class level not inside onItemClickListener

Comment: Sorry, just got what you mean (I think). I'm not extending ListActivity